# Using Noether's theorem to get a constant of motion from a Killing vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, metric-tensor, noethers-theorem

Please note that I will not use summation sign but Einstein's summation convention: repeated pair of (upper and lower) indices are summed over $\sum_{a} A_{a} B^{a} \equiv A_{a}B^{a} = A_{c}B^{c}$

> Given the Lagrangian:
>   $$L = G_{ab} \dot q^a\dot q^b\tag{1}$$
>   And the following equation involving the Killing vector $v^a$ 
>   $$\Big( \partial_a G_{bc}v^a + G_{ba}\partial_c v^a + G_{ca}\partial_b v^a \Big) = 0.\tag{2}$$
>   Prove that $$Q_v = v^a \dot q^b G_{a b}\tag{3}$$ is a constant of motion.
>   **HINT**: Think of Noether's theorem.

**What I have done:**

Noether's theorem states that if $q^a \to q^a + \epsilon k^a$ is a symmetry of the Lagrangian, then $p_a k^a$ is a constant of motion.

- Next I justify translational symmetry. It is not related to my issue with this problem so you can just skip it if you wish.

---

Let's deal with translation.

First, we have to show that translation is a symmetry of the Lagrangian. If we take the derivative with respect to time on both sides of $q^a \to q^a + \epsilon k^a$, we end up with $\dot q^a \to \dot q^a$.

It is justified that $\dot q^a$ terms do not change under translation.

But we are not done yet because $G_{ab}$ depends on $q$. But the following holds:

$$G_{ab}(q^c) = G_{ab}(q^c + \epsilon k^c)$$

So translation leaves our Lagrangian invariant

---

OK, once we have shown that translation leaves our Lagrangian invariant we have to prove that (using Noether's theorem):

$$Q_v = p_k \Big( \frac{\partial (q^k)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda}\Big)_{\lambda = 0} = v^a \dot q^b G_{a b} \ \ \ \ (1)$$

I know how to calculate $p_k$

$$p_k = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^k} = G_{ab} \delta_k^a \dot q^b + G_{ab} \delta_k^b \dot q^a = G_{kb} \dot q^b + G_{ak} \dot q^a = 2 G_{ak} \dot q^a \ \ \ \ (2)$$

**My issue is how to deal with** $\Big( \frac{\partial (q^k)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda}\Big)_{\lambda = 0}$

I know that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \Big[ \frac{\partial (q_j^k)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda}\Big] = \delta_{j}^{k}$$

So I calculated:

$$\frac{\partial (q^a)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda} |_{\lambda=0} = 1$$

$$\frac{\partial (q^b)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda} |_{\lambda=0} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial (q^c)^{\lambda}}{\partial \lambda} |_{\lambda=0} = 0$$

I used also this idea with $q^b$ and $q^c$ and got as the conservative quantity:

$$Q = \dot q^b\Big( G_{ab} + G_{bb} + G_{bc} \Big)$$

Which is wrong...

Besides, I didn't use $\Big( \partial_a G_{bc}v^a + G_{ba}\partial_c v^a + G_{ca}\partial_b v^a \Big) = 0$

So I am definitely missing something.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments & hints:

1. The invariance $\delta L=0$ of the Lagrangian (1) under the infinitesimal transformation $$\delta q^a~=~\epsilon v^a(q), \qquad \delta t~=~0,$$ follows directly from the Killing equation (2).
2. According to [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), the corresponding conserved Noether charge $Q=p_av^a$ is the momentum $$p_a~=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^a}~=~ 2 G_{ab}(q)\dot{q}^b$$ times the generator $v^a$ of the symmetry.